# react router pushState not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a redux action like:

```
import createHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'
import * as loginTypes from '../lib/constants/login'

export function login(){

    return (dispatch, getState) => {

        var message = "hellooww world"
        dispatch({ message, type: loginTypes.LOGIN })

        createHistory.push('/login')
        createHistory.pushState(null, '/login')
        createHistory.transitionTo('/login')

    }
}
```

Here I simply want to redirect my after my action is dispatched but it is not being redirected... What might be the issue here ?? Need help

Answer (score 0):

You got at least two problems there.

1º) You shouldn't be pushing states in a reducer.

2º) If you want to push states without using context.router, you have to use browserHistory imported from React router, more info [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/12-navigating)

E.G

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

  handleSubmit(event) {
    // ...
    const path = `/repos/${userName}/${repo}`
    browserHistory.push(path)
  },
```

Also, if you are going to use browserHistory, dont forget to use it as your history in your router

```
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory} >{routes}</Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

---- Edited -----

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import * as loginTypes from '../lib/constants/login'

export function login(){

    return (dispatch, getState) => {

        var message = "hellooww world"
        dispatch({ message, type: loginTypes.LOGIN })
        browserHistory.push('/login');

    }
}
```

Comment: I can route it from components and container.. I want to route it from `redux actions` ..

Comment: Any idea how to redirect from actions ??

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` this is what I got when I do that

Comment: what version of React-Router are you using?

Comment: browserHistory was added in 2.0.0, you could try to update it, otherwise you are not going to have a singleton history.